# Sequence of actions with RxSwift

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I'm using RxSwift to simply my code. For my current project I'd like to apply RxSwift's principles to a mess of completion blocks from the LayerKit:

```
layerClient.connectWithCompletion { (success, error) -> () in
  if (!success) {
     // Error     
  } else {
    layerClient.requestAuthenticationNonceWithCompletion { (nonce, error) -> () in
      // Even more blocks
    }
  }
}
```

I'm thinking about something like this:

```
// In extension
public func rx_connect() -> Observable<Bool> {
    return create { observer in

        self.connectWithCompletion { (success, error) -> ()in
            if (success) {
                observer.on(.Next(success))
                observer.on(.Completed)
            } else {
                observer.on(.Error(error))
            }
        }
        return NopDisposable.instance
    }
} 

public func rx_requestAuthenticationNonce() -> Observable<String> {
    // Same for annother method
}

// In AppDelegate
self.layerClient.rx_connect()
 .then() // requestAuthenticationNonceWithCompletion and use the nonce for next action
 .then()
 .subscribeNext(…
 .onError(… // To catch all errors
```

RxSwift does not have a `then()` method. Is there another way to do this chaining stuff or am I thinking wrong on how to use ReactiveX in general?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right, RxSwift doesn't have the `then` operator because the name is very risky.

`then` can be a lot of things in the Reactive Extensions world a `map` a `flatMap` or even a `switchLatest`, depending on the context.

In this case I would suggest to use a `flatMap` because that is going to be returned using a `map` is an Observable of Observables, that in most cases are hard to combine and manage. So I would do:

```
self.layerClient.rx_connect()
 .flatMap(){ _ in
   return rx_requestAuthenticationNonce()
             .catchError(displayError)
 }
 .subscribeNext(…
 .onError(… // To catch all errors
```

I would use `flatMap` instead of `map` in this case because I am then able to catch errors without terminating the sequence in case `rx_requestAuthenticationNonce()` fails.

Be careful in using the `catchError` operator, this operator will terminate the sequence after recovering and any extra event will be ignored after that.

Comment: if `then` name is a problem, we can choose a better name, but this use case is very common

Answer (score 3):

This is authorization part in my project. Just an example for chaining requests. It turns the result of chained requests into a bool answer. It use 'flatMap' because result of old request is used in building new request. Otherwise, you can use 'concat' instead of 'flatMap'.

```
       let client = RxSimpleLazyHttpClient.sharedInstance
       let uuid = UIDevice().identifierForVendor!.UUIDString

       let helloheaders = ["X-User-Identifier": "id:" + uuid]
       let helloRequest: Observable<StringDictionary> = client.makeRequest(verb: .GET, url: NSURL(string: self.API_HOST + self.API_HELLO)!, parameters: [:], headers: helloheaders)
            .map { result in
                if (self.enableDebugOutput) {
                    self.debug(result)
                }

                let json = JSON(data: result.2!)
                let userKey = json["user_key"].string
                let userSecretHash = json["user_secret_hash"].string

                return ["user_key": userKey ?? "", "user_secret_hash": userSecretHash ?? ""]
            }

        let jointAuthRequest: (StringDictionary -> Observable<StringDictionary>) = { [unowned self] stringDictionary in
            Logger.D(stringDictionary.debugDescription)

            let userKey = stringDictionary["user_key"]
            let headers = ["X-User": userKey ?? ""]
            return client.makeRequest(verb: .GET, url: NSURL(string: self.API_HOST + self.API_AUTH)!, parameters: [:], headers: headers)
                .map { result in

                    if (self.enableDebugOutput) {
                        self.debug(result)
                    }

                    let json = JSON(data: result.2!)
                    let nonce = json["nonce"].string
                    var result = [String: String]()
                    result["nonce"] = nonce

                    return result.merge(stringDictionary)
                }
        }

        let jointAuthNonceRequest: (StringDictionary -> Observable<StringDictionary>) = { [unowned self] stringDictionary in
            Logger.D(stringDictionary.debugDescription)

            let nonce = stringDictionary["nonce"] ?? ""
            let userSecretHash = stringDictionary["user_secret_hash"] ?? ""
            let headers = ["X-Pass": (userSecretHash + nonce).sha1().webSafeBase64()]

            return client.makeRequest(verb: .GET, url: NSURL(string: self.API_HOST + self.API_AUTH + "/" + nonce)!, parameters: [:], headers: headers)
                .map { result in

                    if (self.enableDebugOutput) {
                        self.debug(result)
                    }

                    let json = JSON(data: result.2!)
                    let sessionKey = json["session_key"].string
                    let sessionSecret = json["session_secret"].string
                    var result = [String: String]()
                    result["session_key"] = sessionKey
                    result["session_secret"] = sessionSecret
                    return result.merge(stringDictionary)
                }
        }

        let jointResult: (StringDictionary -> Observable<Bool>) = { result in
            let userKey = result["user_key"]
            let userSecretHash = result["user_secret_hash"]
            let sessionKey = result["session_key"]
            let sessionSecret = result["session_secret"]

            if userKey == nil || userSecretHash == nil || sessionKey == nil || sessionSecret == nil {
                Logger.D("Auth Fail")
                return just(false)
            }

            /* You can store session key here */

            return just(true)

        }

        return helloRequest
            .shareReplay(1)
            .observeOn(RxScheduler.sharedInstance.mainScheduler)
            .flatMap(jointAuthRequest)
            .flatMap(jointAuthNonceRequest)
            .flatMap(jointResult)
```

This is the 'makeRequest' method.

```
public func makeRequest(verb verb: Alamofire.Method, url: NSURL, parameters: [String : String]?, headers: [String : String]?) -> Observable<RxRequestResult> {
    return create { observer in
        Alamofire.request(verb, url, parameters: nil, encoding: ParameterEncoding.URL, headers: headers)
            .response { request, response, data, error in
                observer.onNext((request, response, data, error))
            }
        return AnonymousDisposable {
            // when disposed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: using `concat`, both requests must be the same type